# How to know the key of a DRF Serializer DictField from within that field's child?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, deserialization

Let's say we have some Django Rest Framework `Serializer` (we'll call it "`serializer`") that has a custom `DictField` as one of its fields. Within that custom `DictField`, the child field is tasked with recording the dictionary key that it is the value of whenever `serializer.save()` is called.

How would one go about knowing the key of the dictionary being deserialized when interpreting the internal value to be saved?

```
class ChildField(Serializer):
    parent_key = CharField()

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        # At this point, the likely candidate for the
        # key is self.field_value, however, self.field_value
        # is actually an empty string, ''.

        # data['parent_key'] = ???

        return super().to_internal_value(data)

class ParentField(DictField):
    child = ChildField()
```

Assume the data being deserialized is the following:

```
{
    "the_dictionary": {
        "key_we_want_to_save": {
            "arbitrary_other_child_data": True
         }
    }
}
```